# Is there a less verbose idiom for unpacking an optional in C++?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdoptional

In the project I am currently working on I find myself writing a lot of code that looks like the following, where, `get_optional_foo` is returning an std::optional:

```
//...
auto maybe_foo = get_optional_foo(quux, ...)
if (!maybe_foo.has_value())
    return {};
auto foo = maybe_foo.value()
//...
// continue on, doing things with foo...
```

I want to bail out of the function if I get a null option; otherwise, I want to assign a non-optional variable to the value. I've started using the convention of naming the optional with a `maybe_` prefix but am wondering if there is some way of doing this such that I don't need to use a temporary for the optional at all? This variable is only ever going to be used to check for a null option and dereference if there is a value.

Comment: Why not just treat it as a pointer?  `auto foo = get_optional_foo(quux, ...)
if (!foo) return {}; ... foo->some_member;`

Comment: arrow syntax works with std::optional?

Comment: Yep.  It's made to emulate a pointer except no dynamic allocation. You can also dereference it.

Comment: I didnt know this. Write it up as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: If you have a lot of them, add .value() after the call and catch std::bad_optional_access

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an intermediate object. `std::optional` supports a pointer interface to access it so you can just use it like:

```
//...
auto foo = get_optional_foo(quux, ...)
if (!foo)
    return {};
//...
foo->some_member;
(*foo).some_member;
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortest I can think of:

```
auto maybe_foo = get_optional_foo(quux, ...)
if (!maybe_foo) return {};

auto &foo = *maybe_foo; // alternatively, use `*maybe_foo` below
```

If you have multiple optionals in the function and it's very unlikely they'll be empty you can wrap the whole thing with a `try - catch`.

```
try {
  auto &foo = get_optional_foo(quux, ...).value();
  auto &bar = get_optional_bar(...).value();
  ...
} catch (std::bad_optional_access &e) {
  return {};
}
```

Comment: If you want shorter, you can write `return maybe_foo ? *maybe_foo : {}`.

Comment: If we wanted to return, then we could just use `return maybe_foo.value_or({});` though.

Comment: @ypnos Clang complains about this: `error: initializer list cannot be used on the right hand side of operator ':'`.

Comment: @Kostas That would make an unnecessary default constructor call if the condition is false.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat For `value_or({})`? I'm sure any decent compiler is happy to optimize this with copy elision.

Comment: What I'm saying is, if the optional already stores a value, `{}` will still default-construct a new object, even if it's not needed. If the default constructor body is not visible, the compiler has to assume it could have side effects, and has to call it.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different than what you are asking, but consider:

```
  if (auto foo = get_optional_foo(1)) {
    // ...
    return foo->x;
  } else {
    return {};
  }
```

This places the main body of the function in an `if()` block, which may be more readable.